# Runtime error 5631

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, runtime-error, mailmerge

I am trying to generate certificates using the records from my Excel master data file. My coding throws me a VBA error "Runtime error - 5631; Word could not merge the main document with the data source because the data records were empty or no data records matched your query options" every alternate time.

For some data, the code works, whereas for most of the time, it throws error 5631 in the line `.Execute Pause:=False`
There are records inside the file, so I know there is something wrong with my Query itself.

> ***Other info:***
>   Temp1 = Cookies mailmerge word template,
>   Temp2 = Chocolates mailmerge word template,
>   Temp3 = Drinks mailmerge word template
>   Sheet1 = Cookies sales excel data,
>   Sheet2 = Chocolates sales excel data,
>   Sheet3 = Drinks sales excel data

My complete code:

```
Sub Generate_Cert()

Dim wd As Object
Dim wdoc As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim isInvalid As Boolean

Dim statement, fileSuffix, datasource As String
Dim aSheet As Worksheet
Dim cDir As String
Dim wdName As String

Const wdFormLetters = 0
Const wdOpenFormatAuto = 0
Const wdSendToNewDocument = 0
Const wdDefaultFirstRecord = 1
Const wdDefaultLastRecord = -16

SalesDate = Format(Worksheets("SalesMaster").Cells(2, "B").Value, "DDMMYYYY")

On Error Resume Next

'Check Word is open or not
Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If wd Is Nothing Then

    'If Not open, open Word Application
    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If

On Error GoTo 0

'Getting datasource
datasource = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

'Looping all sheet from workbook
For Each aSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

    'If the first cell is not empty
    If aSheet.Range("A2").Value <> "" Then

        isInvalid = False

        'Check sheet for SQLStatement and save file name.
        Select Case aSheet.Name

            Case "Sheet1"
                statement = "SELECT * FROM `Sheet1$`"
                fileSuffix = " Cookies Sales"
                i = 1

            Case "Sheet2"
                statement = "SELECT * FROM `Sheet2$`"
                fileSuffix = " Chocolates Sales"
                i = 2

            Case "Sheet3"
                statement = "SELECT * FROM `Sheet3$`"
                fileSuffix = " Drinks Sales"
                i = 3

            Case Else
                isInvalid = True

        End Select

        'If sheet should save as word
        If Not isInvalid Then

            'Getting new word document
            Set wdoc = wd.Documents.Open("C:\Desktop\Sales Certs\Temp" & i & ".docx")

            With wdoc.MailMerge

                .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters

                .OpenDataSource Name:=datasource, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
                                Revert:=False, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
                                Connection:="Data Source=" & datasource & ";Mode=Read", _
                                SQLStatement:=statement

                .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
                .SuppressBlankLines = True
                With .datasource

                    .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
                    .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord

                End With

                .Execute Pause:=False

            End With

            'wdoc.Visible = True
            wdName = SalesDate & fileSuffix & ".docx"
            cDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\"
            wd.ActiveDocument.SaveAs cDir + wdName
            MsgBox SalesDate & fileSuffix & " has been generated and saved"

            'wdoc.SaveAs Filename:=wdoc.Name
            wdoc.Close SaveChanges:=True

        End If

    End If

Next aSheet

wd.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the On Error Statements and try to locate when exactly the error is being logged. When trying to save will your code handle if the same file name already exists?

Comment: Hello, when I removed both the On Error statements, the code is now throwing me a "Run time error '429' : ActiveX component can't create object". Any suggestions?

Comment: Please specify the Line at which this error has occured.

Comment: At this line : `Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")`

Comment: If you suspect the problem could be with your query, we need to see the query and understand the structure of the underlying data source. Add the following in With...End With: Debug.Print .DataSource.QueryString Copy the result, use the EDIT button below your question to open the question and add that information (paste). Once for a run that works and once for one that does not.

Comment: Siva's thought is a red-herring. You need that On Error. As long as it's followed by On Error GoTo 0 errors will be generated for the rest of the code, and, indeed, you did report the error on the line where it occurred - Siva simply did not read carefully enough.

Comment: Dear Cindy, thank you so much for your prompt reply & quick examination of my code. And, sorry, regarding the Debug.Print . DataSournce.QueryString, I have not used this feature before. And I'm not sure where to add in my code. I will try googling this feature & re-run my program & follow up again. Thank you loads once again! :)

Comment: When querying excel pretty sure mysql style backticks `` are not valid, use angle brackets `"SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"`

Comment: The Connection string in OpenDataSource is wrong - at the moment it will say something like  "Data Source=c:\excel\mydata.xlsx;Mode=Read;" or some such. It needs to start something like "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" (depends on the version of Windows/Office). But you may be able to remove the Connection parameter altogether.

Comment: @bibadia Thank you for your comments. It will say "Data source = c:\exce;\mydata.xlsx;Mode=Read" in my code? or in the Debug print that CindyMeister mentioned? I still cannot figure out how to come up with the Debug print that she asked me to do =_=" :-(

Comment: @Dragon :You can put "Debug.Print .querystring" immediately after "With .datasource".When you run the code from the VB Editor, the output of the debug.print will appear in the Immediate Window in the VB editor.You may need to use the View menu to display that window. Alternatively,use "Msgbox.querystring". NB does each sheet have a row of column headers containing field names, and does the data start in row 2?

Comment: @Dragon: That is, "Msgbox .querystring"

Answer (score 1):

This error was occurring because my source excel document was not saved before the Mailmerge execution. No need to save the word document, as there was no pre-processing necessary before the Mailmerge execution.

So I basically declared wBook as workbook & added this : `wBook.Save`

```
Sub Generate_Cert()

Dim wd As Object
Dim wdoc As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim isInvalid As Boolean

Dim statement, fileSuffix, datasource As String
Dim wBook As Workbook
Dim aSheet As Worksheet
Dim cDir As String
Dim wdName As String

Const wdFormLetters = 0
Const wdOpenFormatAuto = 0
Const wdSendToNewDocument = 0
Const wdDefaultFirstRecord = 1
Const wdDefaultLastRecord = -16

wBook.save '<~~~~~~~ SAVE BEFORE MAILMERGE STARTS
SalesDate = Format(Worksheets("SalesMaster").Cells(2, "B").Value, "DDMMYYYY")

On Error Resume Next

'Check Word is open or not
Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If wd Is Nothing Then

    'If Not open, open Word Application
    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If

On Error GoTo 0

'Getting datasource
datasource = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

'Looping all sheet from workbook
For Each aSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

    'If the first cell is not empty
    If aSheet.Range("A2").Value <> "" Then

        isInvalid = False

        'Check sheet for SQLStatement and save file name.
        Select Case aSheet.Name

            Case "Sheet1"
                statement = "SELECT * FROM `Sheet1$`"
                fileSuffix = " Cookies Sales"
                i = 1

            Case "Sheet2"
                statement = "SELECT * FROM `Sheet2$`"
                fileSuffix = " Chocolates Sales"
                i = 2

            Case "Sheet3"
                statement = "SELECT * FROM `Sheet3$`"
                fileSuffix = " Drinks Sales"
                i = 3

            Case Else
                isInvalid = True

        End Select

        'If sheet should save as word
        If Not isInvalid Then

            'Getting new word document
            Set wdoc = wd.Documents.Open("C:\Desktop\Sales Certs\Temp" & i & ".docx")

            With wdoc.MailMerge

                .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters

                .OpenDataSource Name:=datasource, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
                                Revert:=False, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
                                Connection:="Data Source=" & datasource & ";Mode=Read", _
                                SQLStatement:=statement

                .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
                .SuppressBlankLines = True
                With .datasource

                    .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
                    .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord

                End With

                .Execute Pause:=False

            End With

            'wdoc.Visible = True
            wdName = SalesDate & fileSuffix & ".docx"
            cDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\"
            wd.ActiveDocument.SaveAs cDir + wdName
            MsgBox SalesDate & fileSuffix & " has been generated and saved"

            'wdoc.SaveAs Filename:=wdoc.Name
            wdoc.Close SaveChanges:=True

        End If

    End If

Next aSheet

wd.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

End Sub
```